# Passing countdown timer value to next activity

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

i'm trying to pass the countdown timer value as textview to next activity, but i don't know how, do i need do use intent.putextra() ?
There is my code:

```
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timpRamas.setText(String.format("%d:%d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(c1_1.this,TimpExpirat.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: please add `android-studio` tag only if the issue is related to the android studio IDE itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass the data of the textView to the next activity and in the next activity you can set the data in another view or do whatever  with it:

```
    public void onFinish() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(c1_1.this,TimpExpirat.class);
        intent.putExtra("data" , timpRamas.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

In the TimpExpirat activity:

```
//get the data in onCreate()

Intent intent = getIntent();
String time = intent.getStringExtra("data");

//time now has the time that was last set on your textview, you can set it
//to a new textview or do whatever with it.
```

Comment: Thanks bro it works, but only one thing, how can i set it to keep going when opening next activity?<3